# How to truncated tag with AES GCM?

Tags: android, aes-gcm

I'm using `AES/GCM` encryption and I'm trying to reduce tag from *128 bits* to *32 bits*.
I've found some documentation about `GCMParameterSpec` method which is supposed to do this work.

You can see my code bellow:

```
    Cipher cipher = null;
    try {

        byte[] input = Utils.hexStringToByteArray("d9313225f88406e5a55909c5aff5269a");
        byte[] keyByte = Utils.hexStringToByteArray("cfa2b0719afe65b60b1461cdc6a7f7e3");

        SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(keyByte, "AES");
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        GCMParameterSpec spec = new GCMParameterSpec(32, Utils.hexStringToByteArray("000000000000000000000000"));
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, spec);
        /*byte[] aad = Utils.hexStringToByteArray("000000");
        cipher.updateAAD(aad);*/

        final byte[] encrypted = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(0)];
        cipher.update(input, 0, input.length, encrypted, 0);  //Not being updated for current data.

        //Tag output
        byte[] tag = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(0)];

        cipher.doFinal(tag, 0);

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, spec);
        //cipher.updateAAD(aad);
        final byte[] data1 = new byte[16];

        int offset = cipher.update(encrypted, 0, encrypted.length, data1, 0);

        cipher.update(tag, 0, tag.length, data1, offset);
        cipher.doFinal(data1,offset);


    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ShortBufferException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

It sends me this exception:

> java security invalidkeyexception: Invalid value for MAC size: 32

Do you have some issue or can you explain me why it doesn't work?

Thanks.

Comment: GCM is defined for block ciphers with a block size of 128 bits and AES allows 128, 192 or 256 bit key length.

Comment: Why you require 32 bits?

Comment: thanks for reply, I need 32 bits because i'm using Bluetooth low energy and I can't send more than 20 bytes per packet. I need 16 data bytes and 4 bytes for  Gmac tag. I've seen that it was possible to send 32 bits with AES GCM.